# Dealing with optional parameters in facebook developers toolkit method... I get an error when using null

Tags: c#, facebook

I want to do the following:

`facebook.Schema.stream_data data = api.stream.get(null, new List<string> { page_id }, null, null, null, null);`

But I get the following error:

> Error 10  The best overloaded method match for 'facebook.stream.get(int, System.Collections.Generic.List, System.DateTime, System.DateTime, int, string)' has some invalid arguments
>   Error 11  Argument '1': cannot convert from '`<null>`' to 'int'

Does anybody have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by upgrading to version 3 of the facebook developers toolkit api. The new version allows me to send null to facebook (which is what facebook expects).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't convert `null` to an `int` - or indeed to a `DateTime`. You'll need to work out an actual value to pass in - you should be able to look at the API to find out what the default values are, and use those.

Alternatively, if you can use C# 4, you can just name the arguments you *do* want to pass in, and omit the rest.

Comment: The method is a wrapper for a facebook function that only requires some parameters. So, the only parameter I want to specify is the page_id... Is there another way to do this for besides for using C# 4?

Comment: Yes - just find out what the default values are for the parameters you don't want to use, and pass them in.